# Running JavaScript in watir-webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir-webdriver

I am trying to run the following piece of javascript code in my watir ruby script(watir webdriver). I am trying to set the values of a read only form element:

```
@browser.execute_script("oFormObject = document.forms['/order/orders']; oFormElement = oFormObject.elements[\"order[begin_string]\"];")
```

When I do this I get the error, oFormObject is undefined. 

But during executing the following code I didn't get any error:

```
@browser.execute_script("oFormObject = document.forms['/order/orders'];")
```

I want to get the form elements after this that is when I get an error. How should I run multiple lines of JS code in my watir script. Like select a form, get a form element and then set the value of that form element.

Answer (score 10):

```
@browser.execute_script <<-JS
  oFormObject = document.forms['/order/orders'];
  oFormElement = oFormObject.elements[\"order[begin_string]\"];
JS
```

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful and multiple lines of JS code is running for me.